# How to pick image from phone and display it in app outside the android app?

Tags: android, image, kotlin, android-intent

I want to pick an image from device and then display it in the gallery app or another app

I was able only to open the gallery for picking the image.

```
private val imageLauncher= registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) {
        imageUri = it.data?.data!!
    }

        btnChooseImage.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
            imageLauncher.launch(intent)
        }
```

I think I do not store anything in imageUri

Comment: Start an activity using `ACTION_VIEW` and the `Uri` that you received.